# Powershell: How to Populate 2nd ComboBox with csv 2nd Column data?

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell Forms to create a small start up gui that will allow the users to enter information and then submit that information to configure their pcs. I have a csv with 2 columns, one is department and the second is a code for that department. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the combobox that is populated with the 1st column information (departments) that the user is supposed to select and based off of their selection the Textbox would populate with the 2nd column information from the CSV of that row, thus giving the code. I have been using this post [Populate combobox based on selection of another combobox - Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727139/populate-combobox-based-on-selection-of-another-combobox-powershell) But i can't quite get it. Would someone be so kind to use the code in this former post to give me an example?

Update: I ended up solving this by doing the following, so I hope this helps others in the future.

```
    $comboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
       $selectedItem = $comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
       $selectedValue = ($csvData | Where-Object {
          $_.'column_1' -eq $selectedItem}).'column_2'
       $textBox1.Text = $selectedValue
    })
```

Comment: You could just read the CSV twice, and pull in the data set one for each column to your GUI elements. The link you point to give you all you require, other than what I just stated.